# How do you add mapping of struct array in ink?

Tags: ink, smart-contract

How to create a mapping of a vector of struct, also how to assign value and get the value in this data structure. I didn't find the documentation on the official doc. Is there any downside to using such a data structure in the context of smart contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of an array of structs, you can use a vector of structs to add on mapping. Here is an example:

```
list_of_proposal: Mapping<AccountId, Vec<Proposal>>

pub struct Proposal{
....
...
}
```

// Get list_of_proposal (vector of structs)

```
pub fn get_proposal(&self) -> Vec<Proposal> 
{  
let proposal =
self.list_of_proposals(&self.env.caller());  
proposal 
.... 
}
```

//For add a new proposal

```
pub fn set_proposal(&self)
{
let vec = Vec::new();
let new_proposal = Proposal
{
...
...
}
vec.push(new_proposal);
self.list_of_proposal.insert(&vec);
}
```